# How worldwide company register their domain name?

Tags: dns, registration

Let's just say I have the ambition to make my company become worldwide company, do I register all the domain names individually just like what you would do on single domain name or is there different way of doing it.

for example, how Yahoo, Google, facebook, etc register their domain name worldwide.

Any information would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about company operations - not programming ...

Comment: @marc_s No, it's about worldwide dns registering. Of course that's off topic too, but it has nothing to do with company operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be simply a case of buying each Domain you want for your website .co.uk/.com/.net/.org and pointing them either at the same website or different website depending on your companies goal. If you got back to your hosting company (or whoever you purchased the domain from) they should have the others there for you to purchase (unless another company or someone has brought them already)....

Thanks,

Charles